# How to change the proportion of raster gridcell values

Tags: r, raster

In a sample raster `r` how can I change the proportion of pixel value `84` to `25%` from `9%` as you see in  `per_84`?  I.e. I want to increase the number of pixels with pixel value `84` and decrease the number of pixels with other values with the following condition.

The increase of the proportion of `84` from `9%` to `25%` comes as follows:`9%` (of `84`) is already in the raster. Out of the remaining `16%`
`6%` comes from pixel value `90`, `5%` from pixel value `85`, and the remaining `5%` comes from pixel value `80`.

```
set.seed(200)
r <- raster(ncol=10,nrow=20)
r[] <- sample(80:90, 200, replace=T)    
plot(r)   
getValues(r)
no_cell_val84 <- cellStats(r,function(x,...) sum(x==84)) 
no_cell_val84

no_grid_cell <- ncell(r)
no_grid_cell

per_84 <- (no_cell_val84/no_grid_cell)*100
per_84
```

Answer (score 0):

Here with "terra" (the replacement of the "raster" package)

Example data

```
library(terra)
set.seed(200)
r <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=20)
values(r) <- sample(80:90, 200, replace=TRUE)
r[13:14,] <- NA
```

The number of cells with value `v` (84)

```
v <- 84
nv <- global(r==v, sum, na.rm=TRUE)[[1]] 
nv 
#[1] 18
```

How many cells do we need to add?

```
nc <- ncell(r)
add <- (0.25 * nc) - nv
add 
#[1] 32
```

Start with a sample that is larger than `add` because we need to remove the cells that already are 84.

```
i <- sample(nc, 2*add)
rv <- r[i]
# remove cells that have value v
i <- i[-which(rv == v)]
# subset to the number we need
if (length(i) >= add) {
   i <- i[1:add]
} else {
   print("the sample is too small")
}
head(i)
#[1]  60  88  39  22 146  10
```

Now update the values and verify.

```
r[i] <- v

global(r==v, sum, na.rm=TRUE)[[1]] 
#[1] 50
```